# Neo4j - Get node containing a list of children

Tags: list, search, neo4j, cypher

I have a Document - [:Contains] -> Keyword relationship. I would like to obtain all the documents having a specified list of keywords. So far I managed to do this:

```
Match (d:document)-[:CONTAINS]->(k1:keyword {keyword:"key1"})
WITH d,k1
MATCH (d)-[CONTAINS]->(k2:keyword {keyword:"key2"})
return d, k1, k2
```

The above query returns all documents containing both "key1" and "key2" as keywords. The problem is that the query has to be modified depending on the number of keywords I am looking for. Is it possible to use a list as the search parameter and modify the list rather than the query itself?

Comment: You'll want to make sure you use `:` for your :CONTAINS relationship, otherwise it's a variable instead of a type.

Comment: Also, do you want documents that contain one or more keyword in the list, or must the document contain all the keywords in the list?

Comment: Ideally I would be able to return the documents contaning one or more keywords and organize them in descending order according to the number of matches. The other (less desired) option is to return the documents that contain ALL the keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UPDATED]

A query like this should work:

```
MATCH (d:document)-[:CONTAINS]->(k:keyword)
WHERE k.keyword IN {keywords}
RETURN d, COUNT(k) AS cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

In this query, `keywords` is assumed to be a collection of keyword strings passed as a [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/). I also assumed that `CONTAINS` is a relationship type, hence I added the `:` prefix.

For better performance, you can create an index on the `keyword` property of the `keyword` node label. (In practice, you should probably give the label and the property different names...).

```
CREATE INDEX ON :keyword(keyword);
```

After this, you may have to alter the original query to cajole the Cypher planner into using the index:

```
MATCH (d:document)-[CONTAINS]->(k:keyword)
USING INDEX k:keyword(keyword)
WHERE k.keyword IN {keywords}
RETURN d, COUNT(k) AS cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Comment: This will return documents that have a keyword from the keyword list, but it won't return documents which contain all keywords in the list. Given the wording of the question, there's a good chance they're looking for a query which all keywords in the list are matched.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, however what you suggested returns the documents containing ANY of the keywords and not all of them. I tried to add _WITH d, k, count(k) AS matchcount_ after the where to get the number of matched keywords per document, but this always returns 1

Comment: See my updated answer. It returns the documents with any matching keywords, ordered by descending number of matching keywords.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it worked. I've also posted an answer with a modified version of what you have suggested, but my code returns only those documents which match all of the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @cybersam suggested, this solution returns only those documents which match ALL the keywords.

```
MATCH (d:document)-[:CONTAINS]->(k:keyword)
WITH d,k, ["key1", "key2"] AS input
WHERE k.keyword IN input 
WITH d, input, COUNT(k) AS cnt
WHERE cnt=size(input)
return d, cnt;
```